# How could i get $f(x|\theta)$ at bayes approach?

Tags: bayesian, posterior

Bayesian statistics approach shows $\theta$ posterior density easily can be get by bayes theorem that is:

$p(\theta|x)=f(x|\theta)p(\theta)/f(x)$

My trouble is about getting $f(x|\theta)$ and $f(x)$ in a given dataset, prior distribution $p(\theta)$ is easy to do i'd assume it as constant density. Should i use kernel density to go through that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what is your problem. $f(x|\theta)$ is the likelihood function. Same as in [maximum likelihood](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/112451/maximum-likelihood-estimation-mle-in-layman-terms) it describes the distribution of the data. Choice of the likelihood function to a great degree defines the statistical model you assume for the data. To choose it, you ask yourself *what distribution would describe my data the best?* This of course needs you to understand the data and familiarity with the [probability distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_probability_distributions). Additionally, there is a whole family of nonparametric methods (see [nonparametric-bayes](/questions/tagged/nonparametric-bayes)).

$p(\theta)$ is the prior. It is the distribution for the parameter of the model. If you assume an ["uninformative"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20520/what-is-an-uninformative-prior-can-we-ever-have-one-with-truly-no-information), constant density, notice that this [leads to canceling out the prior](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/423798/why-are-flat-priors-said-to-be-proportional-to-a-constant)

$$
p(\theta | x) \propto f(x|\theta) \, p(\theta) = f(x|\theta) \times C \propto f(x|\theta)
$$

in such a case, the mode of the posterior distribution [would be the same](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/140168/is-a-bayesian-estimate-with-a-flat-prior-the-same-as-a-maximum-likelihood-esti) as the [maximum likelihood estimate](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/112451/maximum-likelihood-estimation-mle-in-layman-terms). There are however problems with flat priors, because they lead to distributions that don't integrate to one and can sometimes be problematic when sampling. Flat priors are [generally not recommended](https://github.com/stan-dev/stan/wiki/Prior-Choice-Recommendations), you should rather consider a weekly informative one if you have no information that could guide a choice for the informative prior.

As about $f(x)$, by the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability), it is

$$
f(x) = \int f(x|\theta) \, p(\theta)\, d\theta
$$

However notice that when using MCMC sampling, or optimization to obtain maximum a posterior estimate, etc you need to know it only [up to a constant](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/275641/what-does-it-mean-intuitively-to-know-a-pdf-up-to-a-constant), so it is [not needed](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51493/normalizing-constant-irrelevant-in-bayes-theorem) and [can be ignored](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/129666/why-normalizing-factor-is-required-in-bayes-theorem/129711#129711) for most of the practical applications.